# Vulkan - Validation layer callback never being called

Tags: c++, vulkan

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation seems to be available, VK_EXT_debug_report and VK_EXT_debug_utils are reported as being available, yet even when I do something that ought to force a complaint from the validation layer, my callback is simply never being called.

```
const std::vector<const char*> validationLayers = {
    "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation"
};

internal void createInstance(AppWindow* app, bool enableValidationLayers)
{

    if (enableValidationLayers && !checkValidationLayerSupport()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("validation layers requested, but not available!");
    }

    VkApplicationInfo appInfo = {};
    appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    appInfo.pApplicationName = "Hello Triangle";
    appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    appInfo.pEngineName = "No Engine";
    appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

    VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo = {};
    createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    createInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;

    auto extensions = getRequiredExtensions(enableValidationLayers);
    createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(extensions.size());
    createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions.data();

    if (enableValidationLayers) {
        createInfo.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(validationLayers.size());
        createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = validationLayers.data();
    }
    else {
        createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    }

    if (vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &app->renderObjects.instance) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create instance!");
    }
}

VkResult CreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(VkInstance instance, const VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT* pCreateInfo, const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT* pCallback) {
    auto func = (PFN_vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT");
    if (func != nullptr) {
        return func(instance, pCreateInfo, pAllocator, pCallback);
    }
    else {
        return VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT;
    }
}

VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL debugCallback(VkDebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagBitsEXT messageSeverity, VkDebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT messageType, const VkDebugUtilsMessengerCallbackDataEXT* pCallbackData, void* pUserData) {
    std::cerr << "validation layer: " << pCallbackData->pMessage << std::endl;

    return VK_FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `extensions` contains the string `VK_EXT_debug_utils`? 
 That `vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT");` is not returning null?  What are the severity flags and type flags set on `VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT`? There are several points in this where there could be an error but you're not telling us enough to help you isolate where it is.